# How does the orient kwarg of the Pandas read_json function work?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to load raw JSON data from the [BEA data API](http://www.bea.gov/API/signup/index.cfm) into a Pandas DataFrame using the `read_json` function.

Structure of the BEA JSON results are as follows:

```
{"BEAAPI": {"Request":...,
            "Results": {...,
                        "Data": {ALL_MY_DATA_IS HERE!}
                       }
           }
}
```

My current solution is to define a separate function...

```
def json_file_to_dataframe(json_file):
    """Load raw BEA JSON file and convert to a Pandas DataFrame."""
    raw_json_data = json.load(open(json_file))
    tmp_json_data = raw_json_data['BEAAPI']['Results']['Data']
    tmp_data = pd.DataFrame(tmp_json_data, dtype=np.int64)
    return tmp_data
```

I feel like it should be "easy" to load this JSON data into a Pandas DataFrame using `read_json` and appropriately specifying the `orient` keyword arg. Unfortunately the official docs are really ambiguous about the syntax to use for the `orient` kwarg and I have not been able to find any specific examples. Thoughts?

Comment: That's similar to what I did [here](https://github.com/TomAugspurger/dnwr-zlb/blob/master/data_wrangling/other/bls.py#L34). IIRC the BLS data wasn't in any kind of standard form that pandas could easily parse. Good luck!